# Import Error:No module request (on Windows command prompt)

Tags: python, python-requests, python-3.7, urllib3

I have been searching tirelessly for days now. I cannot do 'import urllib' on my command prompt, that is when I run a file that contains 'import urllib' I start to get Import Error:No module request. But if I run it on python.exe, it runs fine. Please help me, what should I do to run my files on the command line to get outputs?Thanks.

Comment: import error simply means that the library is not installed/ found. try a simple ```pip install urllib``` and ```pip install request``` and If you find that the library is installed, just use the command ```path_to_python.exe path_to_python_code```

Comment: You mean I should run pip on command prompt? Please I do not get you.

Comment: yes. pip install on command prompt

Comment: My guess is that you are running Python 3 code in a Python 2 interpreter. The modules `urllib`, `urllib2` and `urlparse` in Python 2 were reorganized in Python 3 into `urllib.request`, `urllib.parse` and `urllib.error`. The module `urllib.request` exists only in Python 3.